# What does this line of javascript do?

Tags: javascript

While looking at the [jslint code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) I saw this line:

```
total = subtotal + (+myInput.value);
```

What is the purpose of the second '+'?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The unary plus is there for completeness, compared with the familiar unary minus (-x). However it has the side effect, relied upon here, of casting myInput.value into a Number, if it's something else such as a String:

```
alert(1+'2'); // 12
alert(1+(+'2')); // 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this notation. I assume this is basically shorthand for parseInt()?

Comment: They're not quite the same, Luke, see here for some information: http://alexle.net/archives/290

Comment: Plus of course it would be closer to ‘parseFloat’. +-casting supports full floating point number literals, including weirdnesses like +'Infinity'.

Comment: actually, the thing `(+foo)` is closest to is the explicit cast `Number(foo)` - in fact, they should yield identical results

Comment: Is there any reason why this should be preferred over parseInt?

Comment: @toast: they do different things: `Number()` and `+` will also convert floats and return `NaN` on invalid input, whereas `parseInt()` will just stop parsing on the first non-numeric character, ie `parseInt('42foo')` is `42`, whereas `(+'42foo')` is `NaN`

Comment: @Christoph: That's handy. I can see where they each could be used and why one would prefer a certain way for different conditions. Thanks

Comment: which is better in terms of execution time?

Comment: In Firefox/Chrome, parseInt comes out 25% faster. In IE/Safari, it takes four times as long. Opera, twice as long. So there's no one conclusion you can draw. In any case, the amount of time it takes is minuscule; choosing one over the other on that ground would be totally a premature optimisation.

Comment: @Luke Dennis: Want a shortcut for ‘parseInt(x, 10)’? Use ‘~~x’.

Comment: @Mathias: that's a 32-bit bitwise op, so it will give different results to `parseInt` for numbers out of range of a 32-bit signed int. eg. `~~'2147483648'`->`-2147483648`

Comment: @ChadBirch 's link is dead right now.  [Archive.org is my friend.](http://web.archive.org/web/20120430135433/http://alexle.net/archives/290)

Answer (score 8):

That's called the "unary + operator", it can be used as a quick way to force a variable to be converted to a number, so that it can be used in a math operation.

Answer (score 3):

The [unary + operator](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/unary-add/) turns things into a number.

Answer (score 2):

The + is to typecast it to a number as others have said. It's needed there because form inputs are always string values, and adding a string to another variable concatenates them together into a new string, even if the string looks like a number.

Answer (score 1):

The unary plus operator is, arithmetically speaking, a noop. But like all other purely arithmetic operators, it will convert its argument to JavaScript's number type and can therefore be used as a shorthand for an explicit cast.

Explicit type casting in JavaScript is done via calling the appropriate constructor functions *without* using the `new` operator.

For example,

```
Number(foo)
```

will convert `foo` to a primitive of type number, whereas `new Number(foo)` would additionally create a wrapper object for the primitive and is therefore equivalent to

```
Object(Number(foo))
```

Similar to this use of `+` is the use of `!!` to convert to boolean type.